# Difference between nt:folder, sling:folder & sling:orderedfolder in AEM?

Tags: aem

I want to know what if is difference between `nt:folder`, `sling:folder` & `sling:orderedfolder` in AEM/CQ?

Also what are cases to  use each of these while implementation?

Comment: to change nt:folder to sling:folder once can do the following (just posting it here because I struggled.a bit with this)

Goto folder properties and change it to "orderable". this will change the the primaryType from nt:folder to sling:orderedFolder. you can uncheck this again to the make primaryType to sling:folder

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- `nt:folder` can be used as a "vanilla" folder node in the JCR
- Using a `sling:folder` allows the folders children to be interpreted using their `sling:resourceType` — e.g. if you had a node "bar" at `/etc/designs/foo/bar`, setting the resource type of "foo" to a `sling:Folder` allows you to resolve bar using its resource type via a script (just like with components), whereas if "foo" were an `nt:folder` this wouldn't be possible (it would just be treated statically).
- `sling:OrderedFolder` can be used when ordering is important, e.g. in the `/etc/map` directory, if you want your entries to be used in order rather than randomly, the ordered folder provides this option. (For most cases, it's not really needed.)